# Looking for a template project for OSM data

Tags: qgis, postgis, osmosis

I have a PostGIS 2 database filled with OSM data for my country via Osmosis. Is there perhaps a template/project (!styling) for QGIS i could download, where i would simply change the provider of data to my own database (different database name and credentials) so i wouldnt have to deal with the tedious styling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filled the database with osmosis, you are almost lost. Because if you want the styling used by the official map, you have to fill the database with osm2pgsql. Difference is that closed ways and multipolygon relations are transformed to Postgis polygons by the tool, and spatial indices are created to make processing faster. Osmosis just stores nodes, ways and relations, as in the .osm planet file. You would have to do the rest manually.

You can try this tutorial to get a map out of osm data:
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/

Comment: Note: My tutorial only deals with road data though.

Comment: Ah, I see, only for routing. So it would be better to use the standard Mapnik toolchain, and forget about Qgis...

Comment: Yea, i used osm2pgsql before, and after doing some research its probably the only usable schema for this. It works nice!

Comment: Well, i created the neccessary styles eventually, still, its a lot of work :>

Comment: Creating the mapnik style file was surely a lot of work too... I think the most challenging is the rendering order to get buildings on top of landuses, major roads on top of minor roads, roads on a bridge over the road under it, and so on. Did you get that looking nicely?